# «продлен по ...» или «продлен до...»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, предлоги

С каким предлогом корректнее использовать следующее выражение:

*Пропуск продлён **до** 30 ноября*

Или

*Пропуск продлён **по** 30 ноября*?

Comment: Наверно, не выражение, а предложение/фраза. Словарь: *Фраза или сочетание слов, часто употребляющиеся в речи.* Выражением сейчас не называют любую фразу.

Comment: Большой толковый словарь определяет выражение так: «4. Слово, фраза, оборот речи». А предложение так: «2. ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Лингв. Высказывание, являющееся сообщением о чём-л.»

Comment: Выражением сейчас не называют любую фразу. Это фраза определённой устойчивости. Словари копируют определение и примеры друг у друга, а это не точное определение.

Comment: всё же думаю, что если словари позволяют считать эти слова синонимами, то такое употребление тоже будет корректным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пропуск продлен **"от"**, то значит и **"до"**, а если **"с"**, то значит **"по"**.

Comment: не всегда есть информация о том, с какого (от какого) числа он продлён. имею в виду, что на самом пропуске может быть написана лишь конечная дата.

Answer (score 0):

Первый лучше, второй плохо звучит.

Сравнить помогут вопросы:
*До какого числа он продлён?

По какое число он продлён?* || Хуже.

В Нацкорпусе ни одного примера с "по". Похоже на то, что это разговорный вариант.